# solve for $x: \cos(x) \cos(15^\circ) - \sin (x) \sin (15^\circ) = \frac12$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $x\in [0^\circ,90^\circ]$: $\cos (x) \cos (15^\circ) - \sin (x) \sin (15^\circ) = \frac12$

I get $\cos (x-15^\circ) = \frac12$

What's the next step?

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos(x+15^\circ)=\dfrac12=\cos60^\circ$$

$$\implies x+15^\circ=360^\circ n\pm60^\circ$$ where $n$ is any integer

Now find suitable $n$ such that $0\le x\le90^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to take inverse cosine: $\cos(x-15^o)=\frac12\implies x-15^o=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)$.

You can get inverse cosine of $\frac12$ from the unit circle. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula $cos (x+y) = \cos x. \cos y - \sin x \sin y $

$\implies \cos (x+15) = \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies x= \cos ^{-1} (\frac{1}{2})$

You can use tables like this to find inverse values :
[Table for trigonometric values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uapU.jpg)